# Use directive as value for ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I need to be able to easily determine whether a user is authenticated within my HTML and in all templates.

My first thought on how to do this was to create a "global" controller and apply it to  which simply set $scope.isAuthenticated = $auth.isAuthenticated.

However, after doing some reading, I discovered that this wasn't considered good practice. Instead, I created a directive, which would just return $auth.isAuthenticated().

```
angular.module('HordeWebClient')
  .directive('isAuthenticated', function($auth) {
    return $auth.isAuthenticated();
  });
```

And then in my templates, I figured I could just use .... This doesn't work, the element isn't rendered regardless of the state of $auth.isAuthenticated.

The Safari error console doesn't show any problems, so I'm stuck on where to start in fixing this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't make a global controller or a directive, make a service.

Comment: This can't work since it doesn't follow the angular directive creation syntax. Could you please provide links to the articles you mention?

Comment: As I understand it, there's no way to call on a service within the HTML. I would have to create a global controller as a bridge between the two. Which would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use .run on your main module.

```
angular.module('app').run(function(){
    if(!isAuthenticated){
        redirectToLoginView();
    }
});
```

More: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: I'm not trying to redirect anywhere, but simply to determine whether to render various elements on the page (for instance, whether to show navigation options that should only be available to logged in users and whether to show login/register templates on the home page).